# how to get the data from the spreadsheet and send it to an html table googel script web

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create create an html table from google spreadsheet data.

However I'm not getting success, can someone help.

create the function dynamically according to the data in the spreadsheet

but it keeps giving the error: "Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'."

JS:

```js
function criarTabela(conteudo) {
  var tabela = document.createElement("table");
  var thead = document.createElement("thead");
  var tbody=document.createElement("tbody");
  
  var thd=function(i){return (i==0)?"th":"td";};
  for (var i=0;i<conteudo.length;i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    for(var o=0;o<conteudo[i].length;o++){
      var t = document.createElement(thd(i));
      var texto=document.createTextNode(conteudo[i][o]);
      t.appendChild(texto);
      tr.appendChild(t);
    }
    (i==0)?thead.appendChild(tr):tbody.appendChild(tr);
  }
  tabela.appendChild(thead);
  tabela.appendChild(tbody);
  return tabela;
}
document.getElementById("tabela").appendChild(google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(criarTabela).Lista_Aguard_Ajuste());
```

GS:

```js
function Lista_Aguard_Ajuste(){
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Remanejamento");
  var data = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow(), 28).getDisplayValues()
  
  return data;

}
```

HTML:

```html
  <div id="tabela"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought that the reason of your issue might be that `google.script.run` returns no values. So in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this case, please modify `criarTabela` in Javascript side.

```
function criarTabela(conteudo) {
  var tabela = document.createElement("table");
  var thead = document.createElement("thead");
  var tbody=document.createElement("tbody");
  
  var thd=function(i){return (i==0)?"th":"td";};
  for (var i=0;i<conteudo.length;i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    for(var o=0;o<conteudo[i].length;o++){
      var t = document.createElement(thd(i));
      var texto=document.createTextNode(conteudo[i][o]);
      t.appendChild(texto);
      tr.appendChild(t);
    }
    (i==0)?thead.appendChild(tr):tbody.appendChild(tr);
  }
  tabela.appendChild(thead);
  tabela.appendChild(tbody);
  document.getElementById("tabela").appendChild(tabela);  // Added
}

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(criarTabela).Lista_Aguard_Ajuste();  // Modified
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that `Lista_Aguard_Ajuste()` in your Google Apps Script works. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [Class google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: @Fragosojp Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.